# Error on JPA Auto-generated primary key

Tags: jpa, orm, oracle11g, jpa-2.0

Entity Object Id:

```
@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
@Column(name="MY_ID")
private long myId;
```

This field is declared in the database as a primary key. When I create the object and try to insert it in the database though persist method of EntityManager, the following error happens:

```
[7/29/16 18:02:00:637 CST] 0000005d SystemOut     O Hibernate: 
    select
        next_val as id_val 
    from
        hibernate_sequence with (updlock,
        rowlock)
[7/29/16 18:02:00:676 CST] 0000005d SystemOut     O 18:02:00,671 ERROR TableStructure:149 - could not read a hi value
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

Is there anything else I need to do? Thanks. The database by the way Oracle11g

Comment: You are getting an error when JPA tries to read your sequence. How have you created the tables and sequence object in the database?  Chances are you might just be missing the @SequenceGenerator to define the sequence object as described here  https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Identity_and_Sequencing#Sequence_objects

Comment: This isn't helpful to the OP, but I was getting this error when I *wasn't specific* about my `@GeneratedValue` strategy. When Hibernate guessed, it guessed wrong. Hibernate thought that I wanted a **SEQUENCE** strategy when I *really wanted* an **IDENTITY** strategy. Being explicit and saying `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)` solved my problem.